# Citing programming packages

Tags: publications, citations, physics, code

I wanted to ask how to cite python packages into a scientific article.

I used a code package for my project and I can not find a scientific publication of the package I used. Exist a standard to cite this type of informatic tools, or a standard way to cite a github page?

In my case I'm using python and in the python packages page [(for example)](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/)  they don't say how this should be cited.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure the package you are citing will still exist in 10 years?

Comment: @markvs Not OP, but I don't see why not. The v1 release was 10 years ago after all. Whether it'll be maintained in 10 years time is a different question.

Comment: That is what I had in mind. If the software is not maintained, the reference does not make much sense. It is easier to just acknowledge: "This project was conducted using <name of the software> made by <...>"